# extraer valor de un arreglo y guardarlo en otro en PHP

Tags: php, array

Hola chicos tengo una duda y no se como hacer, quiero extraer dos valores del segundo arreglo y ponerlo en el primer arreglo, los dos arreglos los venían en JSON pero los converti a un Arreglo para poder trabajar con ellos, en el primer arreglo los valores de `signal_1310` y `signal` siempre vendrán vacíos y `estatus` tendrá datos, y en el segundo arreglo `signal_1310` y `signal` vendrán con datos pero `estatus` vendrá vacío, y lo que necesito es a partir de los dos arreglos generar un nuevo arreglo donde ya contenga todo.

primer arreglo:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
    Array ( 
        [sn] => ZTEGC95E1507 
        [olt_id] => 2 
        [board] => 17 
        [port] => 16 
        [onu] => 2 
        [zone_id] => 1 
        [status] => Online 
        [signal] => 
        [signal_1310] => 
) 
[1] => 
    Array ( 
        [sn] => ZTEGC96B8163 
        [olt_id] => 2 
        [board] => 3 
        [port] => 8 
        [onu] => 1 
        [zone_id] => 1 
        [status] => Power fail 
        [signal] => 
        [signal_1310] => 
    )
[2] => 
    Array ( 
        [sn] => ZTEGC96B470D 
        [olt_id] => 2 
        [board] => 17 
        [port] => 16 
        [onu] => 1 
        [zone_id] => 1 
        [status] => Online 
        [signal] => 
        [signal_1310] => 
    ) 
)
```

segundo arreglo

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
    Array ( 
        [sn] => ZTEGC95E1507 
        [olt_id] => 2 [board] => 17 
        [port] => 16 [onu] => 2 
        [zone_id] => 1 
        [status] => 
        [signal] => Very good 
        [signal_1310] => -29.208 dBm 
    ) 
[1] => 
    Array ( 
        [sn] => ZTEGC96B470D 
        [olt_id] => 2 
        [board] => 17 
        [port] => 16 
        [onu] => 1 
        [zone_id] => 1 
        [status] => 
        [signal] => Warning 
        [signal_1310] => -30.468 dBm 
    ) 
[2] => 
    Array ( 
        [sn] => ZTEGC96B1B6C 
        [olt_id] => 2 
        [board] => 17 
        [port] => 16 
        [onu] => 3 
        [zone_id] => 1 
        [status] => 
        [signal] => Warning 
        [signal_1310] => -30.764 dBm 
    ) 
)
```

necesito que el valor **signal** y **signal_1310** que están en el segundo arreglo pueda ponerlos en primero, ya que en el primero aparecen como vacío, use la función **array_merge()** pero lo que hace esta es que los une a los dos, tienen una idea de como puede hacerlo.

Comment: Eso no tiene pinta de un arreglo sino de un objeto, que son cosas distintas

Comment: @BetaM es un objeto, pero en `response` lo que **parece haber** es un arreglo, que tiene dentro otro objeto. Lo digo por el `[`, que es indicativo de arreglo. Ahora bien, si la estructura es exactamente la que presenta Karla, estamos ante un JSON **no válido**, no se podrá trabajar con él. Por ejemplo, ¿donde cierras el array con `]` Karla? Además, faltan detalles en tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, ¿siempre `signal_1310` es `null` en el primer **objeto**? Pulsa en [edit] para aclarar la pregunta y presenta el objeto real. El objeto actual no validará como JSON.

Comment: Excelentes observaciones @A.Cedano

Comment: si vienen en formato JSON, pero lo transforme a un arreglo